# What is the difference in Kafka between a Consumer Group Coordinator and a Consumer Group Leader?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I see references to Kafka Consumer Group Coordinators and Consumer Group Leaders...

1. What is the difference?
2. What is the benefit from separating group management into two different sets of responsibilities?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

### 1. What is the difference?

The **consumer group coordinator** is one of the brokers while the **group leader** is one of the consumer in a consumer group.

The group coordinator is nothing but one of the brokers which receives heartbeats (or polling for messages) from all consumers of a consumer group. Every consumer group has a group coordinator. If a consumer stops sending heartbeats, the coordinator will trigger a rebalance.

### 2. What is the benefit from separating group management into two different sets of responsibilities?

#### Short answer

It gives you more flexible/extensible assignment policies without rebooting the broker.

#### Long answer

The key point of this separation is that **group leader** is responsible for computing the assignments for the whole group.

It means that this assignment strategy can be configured on a consumer (see [`partition.assignment.strategy`](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_partition.assignment.strategy) consumer config parameter).

If a partitions assignment was handled by a **consumer group coordinator**, it would be impossible to configure a custom assignment strategy without rebooting the broker.

For more details see [Kafka Client-side Assignment Proposal](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Client-side+Assignment+Proposal).

### Quotes from documentation

From the "[Kafka The Definitive Guide](https://www.confluent.io/wp-content/uploads/confluent-kafka-definitive-guide-complete.pdf)" [*Narkhede, Shapira & Palino, 2017*]:

> When a consumer wants to join a consumer group, it sends a `JoinGroup`
> request to the group coordinator. The first consumer to join the group
> becomes the group *leader*. The leader receives a list of all
> consumers in the group from the group coordinator (this will include
> all consumers that sent a heartbeat recently and are therefore
> considered alive) and it is responsible for assigning a subset of
> partitions to each consumer. It uses an implementation of the
> `PartitionAssignor` interface to decide which partitions should be
> handled by which consumer.
>
> [...] After deciding on the partition assignment, the consumer leader sends
> the list of assignments to the `GroupCoordinator` which sends this
> information to all the consumers. Each consumer only sees his own
> assignment - the leader is the only client process that has the full
> list of consumers in the group and their assignments. This process
> repeats every time a rebalance happens.

Comment: Can you expand your answer to explain #2 of my question? Why not use a single combined coordinator/leader?

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Client-side+Assignment+Proposal discusses the motivatition for separation of responsibilites.;tldr flexible/extensible assignment policies without rebooting the broker

Comment: coordinator is also the one which approves/disapproves the commits from each individual consumer is that true?

Comment: This answer is partially copy/pasted from "Kafka: the definitive guide" which can is legally available here: https://www.confluent.io/wp-content/uploads/confluent-kafka-definitive-guide-complete.pdf

Comment: @VikasTikoo ,  is it possible for you to summarize on (2) and post as answer or comment

Comment: @FrancisToth,  is it possible for you to summarize on (2) and post as answer or comment

Comment: @joven, I've summarized on (2) by editing the original answer.