# How does kafka read to the end of the __consumer_offsets topic

Tags: apache-kafka

As I understand it (which may be wrong) there is a topic (with many partitions) in kafka called `__consumer_offsets` which holds all the commits for all group_ids, keyed by group id.

When a group starts up, then the group coordinator (??) needs to read this topic to the end to find the most recent commit for that group id.

How practically can it do that?  If many other groups could be writing commits, then while it is trying to read, the log will be growing - so how does it decide when to stop reading and go with whatever commit it has found?

**Edit**

Just to try to add some precision to why the current answer doesn't really answer the question.  The question here is not about "how can it get to the end in reasonable time", but exactly what mechanism triggers the group coordinator to stop consuming.  There are only a finite number of partitions, so there can be no guarantees that another group id won't be committing to the same partition, therefore the __comsumer_offset topic could be getting longer during the read.

I can speculate on ways it *might* be done, but this is just thinking up how I might solve the problem, with no reference here to have kafka ACTUALLY solves this

1. It could set a timeout, and read for N seconds, assume that __consumer_offsets will never get large and so N will always be long enough to get to the end.  When N seconds off polling completes whatever we saw is used.
2. It could consumer until it gets to a point where a poll times out.  This sounds dangerous because if another group id is commit a LOT then you might get stuck forever waiting for a poll to timeout.
3. It could check the high water mark (end offset) of the partition before it starts reading, and then read until it has read to or past that offset.  Then it wouldn't matter if more was added after the read had started (and we know that new messages are not from this group id so can safely be ignored).
4. Maybe the broker (which has been running for ages) constantly consumes from the __consumer_offsets topic and builds a lookup table of the latest commit, then the group coordinator just asks the broker, rather than reading the topic directly.

Answer (score 1):

Committed offsets are only fetched when a `JoinGroup` network request is received, followed by `SyncGroup` with the partition assignment, which is assigned by the coordinator along with the TopicPartitions and offset data.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/A+Guide+To+The+Kafka+Protocol

After assigned, it's not fetched again. (This means an external process could commit offsets in the middle of your consuming, and it wouldn't affect the group until it rebalanced)

The reason for the large partitioning of the offsets topic is that the hash of the group name is well distrubuted and so the whole topic never needs scanned, only one partition that matches the hash of the key. For any group, offset commits are not expected to be frequent, but any standard consumer can easily consume thousands of events per second. Offsets are just arrays of numbers, mapped to topic names and partitions, so are not large payloads over the network

Related question

[What is the difference in Kafka between a Consumer Group Coordinator and a Consumer Group Leader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42015158/what-is-the-difference-in-kafka-between-a-consumer-group-coordinator-and-a-consu#42017828)

Comment: Also worth noting that it's a compacted topic, so there's only a limited number of offsets to scan through.  Years ago I had a Kafka cluster that silently stopped compacting (old Kafka bug) which meant that eventually it was impossible for new consumers to get offsets without timing out.

Comment: True, so in theory, an in memory map could be built of the latest offsets on every broker, though, I'm not sure if that's the case

Comment: Ok, so are you saying it uses a simple timeout then on the system clock?  As in it will consume from that partition for N seconds, and then whatever it has at that point, it considers the latest commit?

Comment: There's no timeout, no. It just can read really fast. The comment above refers to compacted topics, so there's old data that Kafka automatically removes

Comment: But if there is not timeout, how can it decide when it has reached the end and stop reading - if I connect to a consumer and read, I will just read forever, and the group would never start.  This question is all about how does the group coordinator decide to stop reading from __consumer_offsets.

Comment: As mentioned, it can consume many records and fast (max.poll.records defaults to 500), it's only one partition, and there's not tens of thousands of commits happening in any one partition... A consumer can easily know when it's at the end of any partition. Or, as mentioned, a compacted topic can be built into a Hashmap for constant time lookup. There are timeouts for consumers to join a group, just not to lookup offsets

Comment: "A consumer can easily know when it's at the end of any partition."  How exactly?  Are you saying it checks the watermarks?  What mechanism EXACTLY informs the consumer that it is at the end of the topic, given that more data is constantly being written to the topic from other places.

Comment: When the poll returns zero records. Or, when the consumer starts polling, it can find the exact high offset watermark and not poll beyond that. Yes... Or, it could read files from disk, rather than open any consumer, since the coordinator is one of the brokers that could be hosting the partition containing data for that group, not a remote client... Kafka is an open source project. I don't know all of the internals, but you're welcome to go look exactly how it works, if you truly want to know